# finding it difficult to test AngularJS UI Grid with protractor

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, grid, protractor

I am pretty much new to protractor and testing AngularJS is my first time. I have to test a table which is populated with Angular grid. These values don't have any unique id's to identify them. After doing some research, i found we need to use gridTestUtils.spec.js. I have tried this in my spec file as below:

```
var gridTestUtils = require('./gridTestUtils.spec.js');

describe('get row count of grid', function(){
    it('get the row count of grid1', function(){
          gridTestUtils.expectRowCount('grid1',8);
    });
});
```

This is the only spec file and there is no pageobject file. But this code doesn't seem to run. it says pageObject is not defined.  Can you please let me know how to proceed from here and i am not an expert. please answer in simple and detailed manner as it will be easy for me to understand.

Thank you for your help.

Thanks,
Mallesh

Comment: Could you post the complete error traceback? Thanks.

Comment: The error i get is - Syntax Error Unexpected token <
It points to line no1. i.e var GridTestUtils = require('./gridTestUtils.spec.js');

Comment: Hm. Could you post the contents of `gridTestUtils.spec.js`?

Comment: Did you get the solution? I am in similar situation.

Comment: @rahoolm - yes i was able to use the gridTestUtils and run my tests. what is the exact issue you are facing now?

Comment: @rahoolm you cannot use the gridTestUtils directly. you need change the format to suit protractor. change the functions too - 

    this.datacell = function(gridId,fetchRow,fetchCol) {
        var row = this.getGrid(gridId).element( by.css('.ui-grid-render-container-body')).element( by.repeater('(rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows track by $index').row(fetchRow));
        return row.element( by.repeater('(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid').row(fetchCol));
    };

then call - datacell('gridid',0,0) - to get first cell value.

Comment: So this means that the gridId is necessary. My problem is I am able to get the rendered rows only which are 18 in my case, but how to get all 25 rows (results have 25 rows in my case). How to check each row has a certain text/string present ?

Comment: @rahoolm i faced the same issue, You can get the text of the cell that you can see on your screen. If there is a scrollbar for the remaining rows, you can only get the count but not the text within it.

Answer (score 0):

`gridTestUtils` definitely feels like it may be overkill. Have you thought about testing the page with lower level calls to protractor directly? It's not a lot of code.

```
describe('get row count of grid', function () {
    before(function () {
        browser.get('http://localhost:9000/orwhatever');
    });

    it('get the row count of grid1', function(){
        expect(element.all(by.repeater('row in rows')).count()).to.eventually.equal(8);
    });
});
```

Replace the url with the url of your app, and replace the repeater string with the same string that is in `ng-repeat` in your DOM. If you're not using a repeater, just use the `$$()` function to grab all elements by css-selector instead.